# On Vimeo, how to keep the video on the last image when video ends?

Tags: vimeo

Until recently, by default, after the video ends, the last image of the video was shown (as the end screens). Now, instead, a blackish background with a replay button on left bottom is shown.

How can I revert to the previous behaviour? In the presets I can't see this option. The nearest I can find is `Thumbnail` but, as the name tell, it show the thumbnail instead of the last image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Nothing" end screen, which is what you're thinking of, was changed some time ago to "Empty", returning just a blank/black screen. This change occurred as early as April 2017, but may have been later: https://vimeo.com/blog/post/more-customization-more-engagement-new-end-screen/

I found a workaround to emulate the "Nothing" behavior: set your video's end screen to "Text" and set the text to `&nbsp;`. This text should render as blank space and grey out the last frame.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy. Your `&nbsp;` solution is mostly what I want. I would have prefer to keep the playback controls instead of having only the replay button but I can live with that.

Comment: This no longer works because Vimeo dims the background to overlay the text, even if the text is &nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

I too would really love to know how to do this nowadays. Would love to be able to avoid the outro screen.